# Show / Hide elements based on query string value

Tags: jquery

Have some div elements on a page that I need to hide by default until a form is submitted and the user redirected back to the same page with a query string appended to the url (?success=true) for example.

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("div.show_on_success").toggle(document.URL.indexOf("success=true") !== -1);
});
```

This code shows the divs with class `show_on_success` if "success=true" appears in the page's URL, and hides them otherwise.