# Show/Hide Multiple elements based on query string value

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I found this post about setting up a query to show/hide elements on a page:
**[Show / Hide elements based on query string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852056/show-hide-elements-based-on-query-string-value)**

How do I extend it to show/hide multiple elements?

For instance...
Let's say I have six elements on a page with the following classes: .a, .b, .c, .d, .e, .f

With one query I hide: .b,.d,.f
and another hide: .a, .c, .e

Two different queries that can handle hiding multiple elements.

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Elements can have several classes, separated by spaces in the HTML. What you might do is add a new class to the elements you want to show or hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.b,.d,.f').hide();`

`$('.a, .c, .e').hide();`

Comment: Perhaps my question wan't completely understood...
Using the same model illustrated on the link above, how do I hide multiple elements to that specific query?

Comment: @JosephSjoblom That's why it's always a good idea to post the code you've tried.

Comment: Yeah but that was a question by someone else, it wasn't clear that you were using the exact same code...would have been good to post it in your actual question. Anyway, would 

`$("div.show_on_success").toggle(document.URL.indexOf("success=true") !== -1);
$("div.show_on_something_else").toggle(document.URL.indexOf("something_else=true") !== -1);` be any closer to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Or maybe you're looking for `$("div.show_on_success, div.also_show_on_success").toggle(document.URL.indexOf("success=true") != -1);`

Comment: sorry, I probably should have posted code... I'll update my post above.

Comment: ha! Matt B, just realized after reading your posts all I have to do is separate my class names with commas. doh!

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) Yeah, if you were just using spaces before, that means you were checking for descendents with that classname rather than simply checking for multiple classes (just like CSS).