# Swap data value based on query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

We inherited some old code which is in place and working. It is a simple pricing switch between £ GBP and $ USD - the price updates onChange as seen below in the pen.

**PEN link**

https://codepen.io/go6/pen/rNOgaee

```
$(function() {
  $("#curr").on("change",function() {
    var curr   = this.value;
    var prefix = curr=="500"; // or ["usd","yen",...].indexOf(curr); for more
    var sign   = curr=="500"?"":"";
    $(".value").each(function(){
      $(this).text(
        (prefix?sign:"")   +
                $(this).data(curr) +
    (prefix?sign:"")
      );
    })
  }).change();
});
```

**Question**

The price by default is set to USD, as per the data-usd value when the page loads. We want to supply a page URL query string eg /pricing?curr=GBP  which can toggle the pricing to GBP.

**Tried so far but not working**

I have tried a few combinations using this Answer:

[Show / Hide elements based on query string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852056/show-hide-elements-based-on-query-string-value/13852123)

but so far, none have worked. Please can someone assist in implementing a query string sitch of currency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your code:

```
 if(document.URL.indexOf("curr=GBP") !== -1)
 {
    $(".value").each(function(){
       $(this).text($(this).data("gbp"));
    })
    $("#curr").val("gbp");
 }
```

Comment: Nearly there. Thank you. The price updates but the select dropdown val doesn't.

Comment: @wayne That's strange as it should be !== -1 to check if the string is there. For the select dropdown issue I have just updated my answer.

Comment: @Wayne Glad that I was able to help you. If this answered your question, please check the checkmark next to the answer to resolve your question as answered/solved.