# How to Show/Hide element on specifict url/endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, endpoint

Can we make a script that allows to hide certain elements when endpoints are loaded in our website URL???

For example, when someone clicks on a currency option, it creates an endpoint "/?wmc-currency=USD". Or if implemented into the web like this https://www.yoursite.com/product/?wmc-currency=USD.

I want a div or any element to be hidden when "/?wmc-currency=USD" is added to the url.

Any help would be very valuable to me. Thanks very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show / Hide elements based on query string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852056/show-hide-elements-based-on-query-string-value)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function checkEndpoint() {
  if(window.location.search=="?wmc-currency=USD") {
    document.getElementById('testid').style.width = 0;
  }
}
checkEndpoint();

// you can also delete the div if you want but with this, you can always bring 
// it back without having to remake it
```

make sure you change the id for the div you want

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up using, because style.width doesn't hide the text.... So I use display none

```
  function checkEndpoint() {
  if(window.location.search=="?wmc-currency=USD") {
    document.getElementById('testid')style.display = 'none';
  }
}
checkEndpoint();.
```

But still, I thank you very much